# Master/Detail Fragment onAttach called twice when using refs.xml

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using a Master/Detail design on my application, I want to support both phones & tablets.  I am experiencing a strange behavior when I try to use the refs.xml XML reference xml.  When I use this approach my ListFragment gets called twice, below is Logcat from my device.

```
com.project.android D/MainActivity﹕ onCREATE
com.project.android D/ContactList﹕ onAttach
com.project.android D/ContactList﹕ onActivityCreated
com.project.android D/ContactList﹕ onAttach
com.project.android D/ContactList﹕ onActivityCreated
com.project.android D/ContactList﹕ onStart
com.project.android D/ContactList﹕ onStart
com.project.android D/ContactList﹕ onResume
com.project.android D/ContactList﹕ onResume
```

Is this  expected behavior?  How can I avoid this double initialization?

I placed the phone refs.xml in the layout folder, below is my refs.xml

```
<resources>
    <item name="activity_masterdetail" type="layout">@layout/contacts_phone</item>
</resources>
```

I place the tablet version in the layout-sw600dp folder, below is my refs.xlm

```
<resources>
    <item name="activity_masterdetail" type="layout">@layout/contacts</item>
</resources>
```

In my MainActivity I do the following.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
Log.d("MainActivity","onCREATE");

setContentView(R.layout.activity_masterdetail);

if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        return;
    } 
        firstFragment = new ContactsListFragment();
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();

}
```

Here are my layouts.

contacts_phone.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

contacts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <fragment android:name="com.project.android.fragment.ContactsListFragment"
              android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.project.android.fragment.ContactDetailsFragment"
              android:id="@+id/contact_detail_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you certain this is the same instance of ContactsListFragment? Also, could you post your actual layouts?

Comment: Its calling twice because ur coding is in that way. in ur xml u should have been set to a fragment. When ur xml runs first time initialization will happen and calls fragment. again ur creating new object and assigning to fragment manager. so, again it called fragment class.

Comment: I think that depends: if this R.id.fragment_container is, for example, a FrameLayout, he should be fine. If, however, that is *itself* a ContactListDetail, I think that would result in the creation of two fragments.

Comment: Thank you both for your input, @HarshaVardhan you were correct, when using a tablet the view gets initialized when the xml gets inflated.  I added a check to see if the fragment was available with findFragmentById() and only create it if it is not there.